# using lambda to return a concatenated string

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list of user, and on that object i have a property email. Is there a way using lambda in c# to return a single string of each users email in a format of "email1;email2;email3" without any semicolon at the end. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Assuming your list of `User` objects is called `users`:

```
string emailList = string.Join(";", users.Select(u => u.Email));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from user in listOfUsers
select string.Join(";", user.Emails);
```

Thanks yamen for spotting the error

```
select string.Join(";", user.Emails.ToArray());
```